# Refresh animation and then redirect to different url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This might be a very noob question... but I am not able to figure it out.

I have a page which has one button..

What I want is.. when I click on that button then it shows an animation of "processing"

like this

http://ajaxload.info/

and then after few seconds.. forward to a url

say google.com

I am sure it is very trivial.. But I am not able to think about it.

So far what I have is just a button :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to call the location after two seconds..`window.loaction` to redirect

try this

**HTML**

```
<button id="buttonId">click</button>
<img src="loading.gif" id="imgid" style="display:none"/>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
   $('#imgid').show(); //this is where you'll show your loading gif
   setTimeout(function(){window.location="http://google.com";}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Hi... sorry for asking probably a very silly question but how do i associate my loading gif with "imgid"..

Comment: just call a img tag to show the loading gif in the place you wanted...hide it first...and then  show that on click.. :)..that should do the tricks..updated check.. hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

you havent told how you are animating, if you are using [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

it provides a complete callback in which you can make the redirect like

```
 $(/*your selector*/).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    location.href='www.google.com';
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ymXG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try on `.click()` and use `setTimeout()`:

```
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     $('body').addClass('processing'); // <---------css class with bg img of loading
     setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
     },2000); //<---------after 2 sec page redirect to specified location.
  });
});
```

better to use this way:

```
$('button').click(function () {
   $(this).after('<img src="http://www.ebay.vn/assets/96ab871/images/loading.gif" />');
   setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.href = 'http://jsfiddle.net/6nMKb/';
   }, 2000);
});
```